# Prevent browser scrolling to hash on page load

Tags: javascript, jquery

Using `localscroll` on ready but the browser snaps to hash on ready. How do I prevent that and have it scroll to the top no matter what?

if this is not possible. How do you offset the position of the `window.location` of hash?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Use `$(window).scrollTop(0);`

```
$(function(){
    $(window).scrollTop(0);
});
```

Comment: Implicit jQuery requirement. Library not mentioned.